# How to bring related trashed records in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, records

In my application I have notes which can be created by a user. User can also create folders and can move notes to folders. User can also trash folders and notes. I also have a trash can in my app.

When a user trashes his/her folder then every note in the folder is also trashed.

The problem is that when I show trashed folders in the "Trash Can" then trashed notes do not get retrieved with this code snippet.

if I go to db and manually make a note untrashed then i do get the note with trashed folders listing.

Here is my code like:

```
$trashed_folders = Folder::onlyTrashed()->where('user_id', $user->id)->with('note')->get();
```

Thanks in advance for the helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to eager load trashed notes as well.

```
$trashed_folders = Folder::onlyTrashed()
    ->where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->with(['note' => function ($query) {
        $query->withTrashed();
    }])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you @Morteza Rajabi. this solves my issue. just edit your answer and change withTrashed to onlyTrashed. then i will accept it as answer for my question. Anyways you did the job